# Pythonic way to print 2D list -- Python

Tags: python, list, multidimensional-array

I have a 2D list of characters in this fashion:

```
a = [['1','2','3'],
     ['4','5','6'],
     ['7','8','9']]
```

What's the most pythonic way to print the list as a whole block? I.e. no commas or brackets:

```
123
456
789
```

Answer (score 10):

There are a lot of ways. Probably a `str.join` of a mapping of `str.join`s:

```
>>> a = [['1','2','3'],
...          ['4','5','6'],
...          ['7','8','9']]
>>> print('\n'.join(map(''.join, a)))
123
456
789
>>>
```

Comment: Oh right! Arrays, lists and arraylists... always screwing me up!

Comment: Always here to try to improve an already good answer :) could be worth a bench to compare `join(map(''` vs `join([''.join(x) for x in a])`. In the latter, the outer `join` knows the size of the list and the items and allocates the output string in one go.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre yeah, if performance really were an issue, probably materializing into a `list` will be faster. Likely, this code won't be performance critical. From the point of view of style and ease, I would be OK with this.

Comment: compiled `map` makes up for the speed loss of the listcomp. A generator comprehension would be the slowest.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Currently performance *is* priority, as the 2d list is pretty massive. What would be the most efficient way be in this case?

Comment: If memory isn't a concern, the either the above or maybe `print('\n'.join(list(map(''.join, a))))` if you are on Python 3. In any event, you can just benchmark with a couple large lists using the [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) module. Indeed, the "Basic examples" in the docs are very similar to your situation...

Comment: And, if performance is really critical, you may consider using a `bytearray`. This is a mutable version of a `str` in Python 3, allowing for fast-conversion between a list-like mutable data-structure and a string...

Comment: @Graviton maybe a `list` of `bytearray`s would be the best... anyway, you can benchmark it!

Comment: Great! I'll look into your suggestions... Off to to some benchmarking.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Last question: How would I efficiently print a list of bytearrays without a generator to to decode it?

Comment: @Graviton actually, I didn't consider the bytes-to-string conversion overhead, probably not a good idea anyway.

Comment: Note that this won't work if the elements of `a` aren't strings, unlike a normal `print(one_d_list)`. For an answer that works even when the elements aren't strings, use [`for x in a: print(*x, sep='')`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45040488/7129538)

Answer (score 3):

Best way in my opinion would be to use [`print`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) function. With `print` function you won't require any type of joining and conversion(if all the objects are not strings).

```
>>> a = [['1','2','3'],
...      ['4', 5, 6],   # Contains integers as well.
...      ['7','8','9']]
...

>>> for x in a:
...     print(*x, sep='')
...
...
123
456
789
```

If you're on Python 2 then print function can be imported using `from __future__ import print_function`.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```py
import os

array = [['1','2','3'],
         ['4','5','6'],
         ['7','8','9']]
print(os.linesep.join(map(''.join, array)))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for *Pythonic* then you surely need a generator comprehension:

```
print('\n'.join(''.join(i) for i in array))
```

Comment: in the case of `join`, passing a list comprehension instead is faster because `join` creates one anyway (needs that to pre-compute the size): `'\n'.join([''.join(i) for i in array])` even if it's uglier :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Yup, [here's where the conversion happens](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/stringlib/join.h#L22).

Comment: Thanks for that @Jean-FrançoisFabre, I didn't know that. OTOH, the OP didn't ask for the fastest method. ;-)