# How to print a 2D list in different lines

Tags: arrays, list, python-3.x

I have a list of lists, just like `[['x','s','d']['a','q','e','d']['q','e']]`.
I want to print just like this:

```
xsd
aqed
qe
```

Three lists in three lines.

I always print all elements in one line. How to print the list in this fashion?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pythonic way to print 2D list -- Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45027681/pythonic-way-to-print-2d-list-python)

Answer (score 0):

```
_list = [['x','s','d'],['a','q','e','d'],['q','e']]
for element in _list:
    print(''.join(element))
```

This code says that for each element in the `_list` (the 3 nested lists)
join the elements (the characters) of each sublist together and print out the join elements on 3 separate lines.

Suppose `myList = ['a','b','c']` then `''.join(myList)` would return `'abc'`

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help. A proper explanation would [greatly improve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) its educational value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions. Please edit your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Re basvk comment about limitations, it's true that list elements are strings, but what would happen if some were floats, or dictionaries or...?